# How to hide the parent component data when going nested in the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am learning React and trying to build a project which is a simple house listing website. Here I am navigating to the top menu "**List Room**" which is showing in the image and then when the user clicks on the next button I want to go to the List Room 2 component which is also happening but the data of the parent listroom is showing how can I hide this?[image]

```
<Routes>
<Route path = "/" element = { <MainMenu />}>
 <Route index element = { Home />} />
 <Route path = "/listrooms" element = { <ListRooms />}>
    <Route path = "listrooms2" element = { <ListRooms2 />} />
 </Route>
 <Route path = "/login" element = { <Login />} />
 <Route path = "*" element = { <ErrorPage />} />
</Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: If you don't want `listrooms` to remain visible while viewing `listrooms2`, why is it nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `ListRooms2` to be rendered on the nested `"/listrooms/listrooms2"` path and ***not*** render `ListRooms` at the same time then move `ListRooms` to its own index route to only be rendered when the path is `"/listrooms"`.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<MainMenu />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/listrooms">
      <Route index element={<ListRooms />} />
      <Route path="listrooms2" element={<ListRooms2 />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Alternatively you could unnest the routes, e.g. render each individually, using the complete absolute path.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<MainMenu />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/listrooms" element={<ListRooms />} />
    <Route path="/listrooms/listrooms2" element={<ListRooms2 />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```